# Converting dataframes created by groupby with multiple conditions to nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have a dataframe with 10 columns that it follows:

```
df:
   |  x |  y |  z |  t |     a    |  b                    | c  | ....
1: | x1 | y1 | z1 | t1 | [a1, a2] | {b1: 1, b2: 2}        | 0  | ....
2: | x2 | y2 | z2 | t2 | [a3, a4] | {b1: 3, b2: 4}        | 2  | ....
3: | x1 | y3 | z2 | t1 | [a1, a4] | {b1: 1, b2: 3}        | 2  | ....
4: | x3 | y1 | z5 | t3 | [a4, a5] | {b1: 6, b2: 2, b3: 1} | 24 | ....
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

I would like to split this dataframe based on values of 4 columns (let's say columns are: `x, y, z, t`) and convert it to a nested dict like:

```
x1:
    y1:
         z1:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z2:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z3:
             t1: df
             t2: df
    y2:
         z1:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z2:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z3:
             t1: df
             t2: df
x2:
    y1:
         z1:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z2:
             t1: df
             t2: df
         z3:
             t1: df
             t2: df
.
.
.
```

What I did:

```
grouped_df = dict(list(df.groupby('x')))
for x_elem in [*x]:
    grouped_df[x_elem] = dict(list(grouped_df[x_elem].groupby('y')))
    for y_elem in [*grouped_df[x_elem]]:
        grouped_df[x_elem][y_elem] = dict(list(grouped_df[x_elem][y_elem].groupby('z')))
        for z_elem in [*grouped_df[x_elem][y_elem]]:
            grouped_df[x_elem][y_elem][z_elem] = dict(list(grouped_df[x_elem][y_elem][z_elem].groupby('t')))
```

After this function, `grouped_df` becomes like nested dicts of dfs where each key corresponds to a variable of the column as I described on top.

```
type(grouped_df): dict
grouped_df:{
            x1: {
                  y1: {
                        z1: {
                             t1: df,
                             t2: df,
                            },
                        z2: {...},
                       },
                  y2: {...},
                },
            x2:{...},
            x3:{...},
           }
```

It is perfectly working so far. However, this method can be highly costly when working on big dataframes and I am sure there is a better way to do it. Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi, could you show what the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()` and `grouped_df.head(10).to_dict()` look like?

Comment: @Laurent I tried to explain my dataframe and the final result that I want to achieve and got. Please let me know if more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": ["x1", "x2", "x1", "x3"],
        "y": ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y1"],
        "z": ["z1", "z2", "z2", "z5"],
        "t": ["t1", "t2", "t1", "t3"],
        "a": [["a1", "a2"], ["a3", "a4"], ["a1", "a4"], ["a4", "a5"]],
        "b": [
            {"b1": 1, "b2": 2},
            {"b1": 3, "b2": 4},
            {"b1": 1, "b2": 3},
            {"b1": 6, "b2": 2, "b3": 1},
        ],
        "c": [0, 2, 2, 24],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do what you're trying to achieve (I'm a bit guessing here, since, your example is not reproducible):

```py
grouped_df = df.groupby(["x", "y", "z", "t"]).agg(list).to_dict(orient="index")

grouped_df = {key: pd.DataFrame(value) for key, value in grouped_df.items()}

grouped_df = {
    x: {y: {z: {t: df}}} for (x, y, z, t), df in grouped_df.items()
}
```

Using [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) and replacing `df` by `str(df)` to get a more readable representation, here is what grouped_df looks like:

```py
{
    "x1": {
        "y3": {
            "z2": {
                "t1": "    a                   b  c"
                "0  [a1, a4]  {'b1': 1, 'b2': 3}  2"
            }
        }
    },
    "x2": {
        "y2": {
            "z2": {
                "t2": "    a                   b  c"
                "0  [a3, a4]  {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4}  2"
            }
        }
    },
    "x3": {
        "y1": {
            "z5": {
                "t3": "    a                            b   c"
                "0  [a4, a5]  {'b1': 6, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 1}  24"
            }
        }
    },
}
```